# When opening new window, in case if the navigation fails( Document Failed to load - Error Status : ConnectionAborted) it goes back to old content

Tags: c#, webview2

I have winform in application which embeds Webview2 Browser. In some workflows, I open the window that contains webview2.
While closing the window, we clear the data and call the NavigateToString method passing valid empty HTML and clearing the cache as well then hide the winform

```
caller:
        if (!disposed && !priorsWebBrowser.IsDisposed)
        {
          NavigateToString(Utils.Instance.GetAboutBlankHtmlContent());
          priorsWebBrowser.ClearCacheContent();
        }
 
        public void NavigateToString(string htmlContentString)
        {
            if (webBrowser != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    webBrowser.Invoke((MethodInvoker)async delegate
                    {
                        await webBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(m_env);
                        webBrowser.NavigateToString(htmlContentString);
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.CreateMessage().Error("Exception while navigating to {0}", ex, m_url);
                }
            }
        }
```

Implementation of ClearCacheContent

```
public async void ClearCacheContent()
    {
      CoreWebView2Profile profile;
      if (this.webBrowser.CoreWebView2 != null)
      {
        profile = webBrowser.CoreWebView2.Profile;
        // Offset the current time by one hour to clear the browsing data from the
        // last hour.
        CoreWebView2BrowsingDataKinds dataKinds = (CoreWebView2BrowsingDataKinds)
                                 (CoreWebView2BrowsingDataKinds.GeneralAutofill |
                                  CoreWebView2BrowsingDataKinds.PasswordAutosave |
                                  CoreWebView2BrowsingDataKinds.BrowsingHistory);
        logger.CreateMessage().Error("Aks:Clearing the browser cache start");
 
        await profile.ClearBrowsingDataAsync();
        await webBrowser.CoreWebView2.CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync("Network.clearBrowserCache", "{}");
        logger.CreateMessage().Error("Aks:Clearing the browser cache end");
      }
```

Next time while opening the window i see old content being displayed.
Issue: When opening new window, in case if the navigation fails(web_browser_DocumentCompleted -> Document Failed to load - Error Status : ConnectionAborted) it goes back to old content

So instead of NavigateToString if Navigate("about:blank") is performed then its working fine.

Does it make any difference?